# Importing VRML model throws error

Tags: import

I'm trying to import my KiCAD pcb into Blender 2.78c. Unfortunately some of the VRML models make the program throw an error. I tried to recreate the problem by creating a simple 2 part object in FreeCAD(I used KiCAD StepUp to align the models to the footprints) and exporting it to VRML2 format. Then I get the following error message in Blender.

[image]

Can anyone help me solve this?

I found that if I download a 3D model from 3dcontencentral.com in VRML2 format, I can't import that to Blender either.

Thanks,
Tibi

Comment: I found a solution on FreeCAD's forum. See here [http://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?t=10815#p103529](http://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?t=10815#p103529)